# decode this javascript which generates a password based on a master password and a website's name

Tags: javascript, bash, hash, passwords, sha1

There's a website that generates a password by joining a master password with the website's name (e.g. master password=abc and site=google) then hashing that with SHA1 and then coding the resulting hash with Base64. I've been trying to implement that in Bash, but I can't. I mean I can but my results are extremely different from the ones in the website. Help?

The website that generates the password using JavaScript is at http://angel.net/~nic/passwd.sha1.html

And here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CUT=8

echo -n "Enter your master password. "
read -s MASTER
echo -en "\nEnter the site's name. "
read SITE

PASS=$(echo -n $MASTER$SITE | sha1sum | sed -e 's/[ -]//g' | base64 | cut -b 1-$CUT)

echo $PASS | sed -e 's/[\/+=]//g'
```

I'm new to Stack Overflow so tell me if I'm breaking any rule, etc...

Comment: It would help if you could give us an exact example: Master Password, site name, your resulting password and the password that the website in your link generates.

Comment: We'd need to see, at minimum, an example of the translation you're trying to replicate (or the relevant section of code), your attempt (code) so far, and a description of how it's going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Whilst not breaking any rules as such you will get more people to look at your code if it isn't hidden behind a URL shortener. I will edit your question to include the actual web addresses.

Comment: @mikej

I only put the links in a url shortener because stackoverflow was restricting me to a single link. Sorry.

Comment: Even better would be to include your code directly in the question (though including the entire JavaScript source would be a bit much, the bash source is short enough to include).

Comment: @AntonioPT No need to be sorry :) You will be able to include more links once you have built up some reputation on the site. It is good that I've edited the question for you then. Cheers - Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `openssl` command to compute an HMAC digest, and to convert to base64, as follows.

```
echo -n $SITE | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 -hmac $MASTER | openssl base64 | cut -c1-8
```

Comment: Yes! I failed to make up this command line after reading `openssl dgst -h` output ;-) +1 Go for this one, AntonioPT

Comment: Yeah, it took me a bit to go through all of the iterations of that command to finally get the right result.

Comment: Persistence is the key ;-) Obviously the first idea I had was to make use of `openssl` binary, but then I fell back to perl.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds even better than Perl! :D

Comment: OK, this works, but "it doesn't make sense". Shouldn't this be: 
openssl dgst -binary -sha1 -hmac $MASTER$SITE | openssl base64 | cut -c1-8

Comment: Sorry, I got it. HMAC is like a key so openssl is hashing MASTER with a key, SITE.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. It's hashing SITE with the key MASTER. But yeah, that's pretty much it.

Comment: I would like to thanks all the geeks (:D) that helped me out. I'm now using this scheme for my passwords!

Answer (score 1):

For what I can tell by

```
password.value = b64_hmac_sha1(master.value, site.value).substr(0,8);
```

It doesn't exactly concatenates and computes `SHA1`, but rather computes [HMAC-SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) for key and message.

I do not know any command-line equivalent for HMAC calculation, but if you don't mind invoking perl that would be something like

```
perl -MDigest::HMAC_SHA1 \
 -e "print Digest::HMAC_SHA1::hmac_sha1('$SITE','$MASTER')" \
| base64 | cut -c1-8
```

Comment: In that case, what's the equivalent of sha1sum for HMAC?

Answer (score 0):

the script uses the hmac-sha1 algorithm rather than a direct sha1 hash. it then returns only the first 8 characters of the base64-encoded result.

you can find a [bash/openssl implementation of hmac-sha1 here](http://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/) or you can call out to php's [hash_hmac](http://www.php.net/hash_hmac) function.

in php, you can do something like this:

```
password=`php -r "echo substr(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', '$SITE', '$MASTER', true)), 0, 8);"`
```

Comment: The ""bash's implementation of hmac-sha1"" it's a script to access S3 servers (Amazon) thru bash. But thanks anyway.

Comment: No, it does indeed implement it in http://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/source/browse/trunk/s3-common-functions , even though I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: you will find the function in that library. it's not only for s3.

Comment: I'll try to use the function in s3-bash and see if there's any difference with the perl implementation. I prefer using a native bash implementation so I'll maybe use this one.

Comment: No. The code is tooo "optimized" for that specific use, S3. I'll continue using the perl implementation.

Comment: not really, it's pretty generic. if you don't want to use that example, you can use php, perl, etc.